# Importing a asp.net webPart in WebForm website from .Webpart file programmatically (Not a sharePoint Project)

Tags: asp.net, import, webforms, devexpress, web-parts

We have created several user Controls (Ascx) that we render to a webpart zone. Similarly, we have a control containing WebPartManager which is implemented in all the .aspx pages.

I am working on a feature where it is required to Import generated .webpart file on any page using a file upload control.
I am Using devExpress fileUpload control and upon FileUploadComplete Event executing the below-mentioned code.
The code Runs without any error but also doesn't display any web-part in the specified zone. Which is the problem.

```
 protected void WebPartUploadControl_FileUploadComplete(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            string ErrorMessge = string.Empty;
            if (e.UploadedFile.IsValid)
            {
                var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(e.UploadedFile.FileContent);
                xmlReader.Read();

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart = wpManager.ImportWebPart(xmlReader, out ErrorMessge);

                       wpManager.AddWebPart(webPart, wpManager.Zones["Zone5"], 1);
            }


        }
```

I might be missing some fundamental code. If anybody knows the answer kindly help. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. Just in case if someone in future come across a similar problem, this will help.

So, The problem here is the Devexpress File-Upload control is an ajax control, making partial postback thus not updating the CatalogZone of the page which is out of its scope.

The way to deal with it is :

1. Create a new .WebPart file and clone the content of the uploaded file.
2. Re-direct to the same page which fires Page_Load event
3. Execute the above code in the page_Load Event in order to import.

Below is the code to explain just that :

**WebPartUploadControl_FileUploadComplete**

```
        protected void WebPartUploadControl_FileUploadComplete(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

String WebPartFilePath = Server.MapPath("DirectoryWhereYouWantTosaveCloneFile");
            String WebPartFileName = "NameOfYourCloneFile.WebPart";
            
            string FileContent = string.Empty;

            Creating Directory to store data of uploaded file(.webPart).

            Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"] = $"{WebPartFilePath}/{WebPartFileName}";
            if (!Directory.Exists(WebPartFilePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(WebPartFilePath);
            }

            Reading Uploaded file Data

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.UploadedFile.FileContent))
            {
                FileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Copying File Data to the newly Created file 

            if (!File.Exists(Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"].ToString()))
            {
                File.AppendAllText(WebPartFilePath + "/" + WebPartFileName, FileContent);
            }

            e.CallbackData = "Page Settings Imported Successfully.";

            // Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) does not work in while ajax callback in 
               devexpress
            // Creating a callback to current page to trigger Page_Load event.

            DevExpress.Web.ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback(this.Request.Path);
}
```

**Page_Load**

```
if (Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"] != null)
            {
                //Import Webpart Settings
                ImportWebPartsToCurrentPage(Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"].ToString());
                File.Delete(Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"].ToString());
                Session["ImportWebPartFilePath"] = null;

            }
```

**ImportWebPartsToCurrentPage**

```
 private void ImportWebPartsToCurrentPage(String FilePath)
        {
            string ErrorMessge = string.Empty;
            //Extracting All WebParts in the file
            XDocument WebPartXml = XDocument.Load(FilePath);

            //Spliting the each webpart.
            var WebPartDescriptions = WebPartXml.Root.Elements();
            try
            {
                foreach (var WebPartDescription in WebPartDescriptions)
                {
                    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(WebPartDescription.ToString()));
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    // Adding Webpart to page Catalog.
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart = wpManager.ImportWebPart(xmlReader, out ErrorMessge);
                    //Adding webpart to the page.
                    if (!wpManager.WebParts.Contains(webPart))
                    {
                        wpManager.AddWebPart(webPart, wpManager.Zones["ZoneName"], 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);

            }
        }
```